# How to install apache tika on windows

Tags: apache-tika

I gone through all over the internet, but i couldn't find the installation any where. Let me know if any one knows the procedure to install apache tike on windows 10.

Comment: How are you planning to call Apache Tika? Java code? Tika Server? OSGi container? Other? The answer will depend on that...

Comment: I want to call Apache Tika using Java Code and Tika Server.

Comment: Which - those are different! Do you want to call the Tika Server over the network, or do you want to include Tika directly in your Java app and call directly into the API?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tika library as a jar dependency or the tika as a server. There is no option to install the tika as an application. If you are interested in tika server check this awesome article: https://medium.com/@masreis/text-extraction-and-ocr-with-apache-tika-302464895e5f

Answer (score 0):

Apache Tika can installed as a Windows service using [Apache Commons Daemon](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/) package.

Here is an example that installs Tika 2.2.1 as a service named "ApacheTika" with some additional options that you probably need to adjust:

```
prunsrv.exe //IS//ApacheTika --Startup auto --StartMode jvm --Jvm "C:\Java\bin\server\jvm.dll" ++JvmOptions="-Dlog4j.configuration=file:loggingConfig.xml" --LogPath C:\TikaServer\logs --LogPrefix tika-server --Classpath "C:\TikaServer\tika-server-standard-2.2.1.jar" ++StartParams "--host=localhost" --StartClass org.apache.tika.server.core.TikaServerCli
```

And if you want to remove it:

```
prunsrv.exe //DS//ApacheTika
```